Best tool for measuring short duration voltage/current?
I'm reusing a watering timer (Melnor 4-port) by removing the circuitry and using only the latching solenoid-driven valves with my own microcontroller.  I'd like to determine exactly how much voltage/current the original electronics apply to drive the valves.  Power is applied for half second or less. All DMMs I have access to are too slow to show me a stable reading.
I have had success driving the valves with 12V in 0.1-0.2 second pulses, but operation is only 90% reliable. The timer most likely uses a boost controller.

What is the right tool for the job?
A peak-detecting DMM?  A cheap oscilloscope?  An arduino with a voltage divider?

Should I be measuring voltage across the coil or with the coil disconnected?


Thanks!


Are there any part numbers or ratings visible on the existing latching solenoid-driven valves?

@ChesterGillon Nothing obvious. They are most likely made by Melnor in-house.

a simple comparator circuit with an adjustable threshold input and an LED output ... adjust the threshold until the pulse does not light the LED ... then measure the threshold voltage

Best tool would be an oscilloscope to measure voltage across the solenoid.
An arduino with a voltage divider would also work as a poor man's solution.
If your multimeter is too slow, you can add a peak hold circuit:

R1 limits current to avoid damaging the source, and C1 should be large enough to get a reading before the DMM's internal resistance discharges it. You can replace the diode with a diode bridge so it will work with both polarities. It loses voltage due to the diode drop but it will give you an idea.
If it is a bistable valve it may be driven with positive and negative voltage to open and close, so if you use an arduino you can add a protection diode at the output of the voltage divider to protect the ADC input against negative voltage.


I presume you don't actually need to know the voltage, current and duration of the pulse, you just want a circuit that operates the valve.
I designed such a (commercial) circuit about 20 years ago. The solenoid valve only required to be turned off (in an emergency) so was single acting. I think you're asking for positive and negative pulses so you'll need an H-bridge but otherwise the principle should be the same.
I used a low power (low current) invertor to make 12V. The 12V charged a large capacitor. The capacitor could be discharged through the coil with a transistor. I never measured the actual current and duration of the pulse - I just considered the total energy being delivered.
I tried various capacitors until I found the minimum that would reliably operate the solenoid. I then doubled it's capacitance. I think it was a few thousand uF but mine was a big chunky valve.
You'll need a capacitor with a reasonably low ESR so it can supply the current. Once you've got it working single action, add an H-bridge to make it double acting. Maybe something as simple as an L293D would work.
The advantage of what I'm suggesting is that you don't need a power supply that can supply the current needed. You can trickle-charge the capacitor.

My current setup (that I've been tweaking for 4 years) involves a capacitor and relays (two used for H-Bridge), roughly what you are suggesting.  The reason I want to measure the power is that I haven't found a voltage/capacitor combination that produces the same satisfying "click" that the factory driver does.  On the flipside, I am also concerned that I may be driving it too hard and the solenoid might "bounce" (OFF->ON->OFF) from the force.  Certainly, I am also concerned about damaging the coil with too much current.
